# How to solve for angle of “Off Screen Target Indicator” (in A-Frame)

Tags: aframe

[image]

In a 3D game, how do I solve for the rotation of a 2D element – the red arrow – so that it points in the direction of the green 3D entity, relative to where the camera is facing?

Given

- position of camera
- orientation of camera OR position of camera target (where it's facing)
- position of enemy

I want to return the 2D rotation of the crosshair-arrow so that it points to where the enemy is.

I'm using A-Frame.

Seems like the easiest solution would be to solve the 2D x,y screen coordinates of the enemy, and then just calculate the angle to that point from the center of the screen. But how in aframe?